# Access a struct with in a iterator issue C++

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw

I'm trying to access struct elements within an iterator in C++, but the compiler just gives me an error that the struct doesn't contain that elemement. I'm trying to do the following:

```
typedef struct
{
   string str;
   int frequenzy;
} word;

bool isPresent = false;

for(std::vector<word>::iterator itr=words.begin(); itr!=words.end(); ++itr)
{
   if(*itr.str.compare(currentWord)==0){
    isPresent = true;
    *itr.frequenzy++;
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following message:

```
lab7.cc: In function 'int main()':
lab7.cc:27:13: error: 'std::vector<word>::iterator' has no member named 'str'
lab7.cc:29:11: error: 'std::vector<word>::iterator' has no member named 'frequen
zy'
```

Why isn't this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should probably rewrite the body of your `for` loop this way:

```
if (itr->str.compare(currentWord)==0)
//     ^^
{
    isPresent = true;
    itr->frequenzy++;
//     ^^
}
```

The `.` operator has higher precedence than the `*` operator. Therefore, if you really want to use these two operators, you should rewrite the above this way:

```
if ((*itr).str.compare(currentWord)==0)
//  ^^^^^^^
{
    isPresent = true;
    (*itr).frequenzy++;
//  ^^^^^^^
}
```